# Manual code computing

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Studying for exams I have been given a lot of code to **manually compute**. This question its throwing me for a loop.

```
public static int[] mystery(int x) {
    int[] result = new  int[x / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < x/2; i++) {
        result[i] = (i * i) % x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

for:

```
mystery(5)
mystery(10)
```

What I computed was [0, 1] for `mystery(5)` and [0, 1, 4, 4, 1] for `mystery(10)`; however, I believe that those answers are *not* correct.

- When going about questions like these, what strategies may help lead me to the answer faster?
- Also if you conclude to an answer what were the steps you took to arrive at the answer?

Comment: Pen and paper, this is known as desk checking.  Basically, you run the variable names across the top in columns and each line or state as rows...

Comment: Please go into further detail *why* you "believe that those answers are not correct".  That will give us a better vantage from which to offer advice.

Comment: "what strategies may help lead me to the answer faster?" faster than what?

Comment: You don't need to "believe" anything - Run the code if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to `mystery(5)` is correct. 
The array for `mystery(10)` should contain `[0,1,4,9,6]`, since you're calculating `square numbers mod 10` in this case.

In my opinion there is really no strategy to get a result faster. It's all about experience in reading the code.

The steps I took for this particular answer were basically

- look at the argument (x=10)
- look where the argument appears and insert it
- go through the code step by step
- look at first line -> **int division** -> array has size **5**
- look at for loop, insert argument and work with concrete numbers -> `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` => so `i` goes from **0** to **4**
- look at expression and decide, which values are changing and which ones are fixed -> `result[i] = (i*i)%10;`
- Think, what loop does => `i`th square number mod 10 goes into array at index `i`
- So result should be `[0,1,4,9,6]`

Answer (score 0):

The key thing you should observe when reading this method is that the iterations of the loop are data-flow independent; the effect of iteration `i` can be analyzed in isolation, without needing to know what happened at any other iterations.

Thus there's really only one fact you need to be thinking about: *result<sub>i</sub> = i<sup>2</sup> mod x*. Then you can forget about the code and just do the math.

Where *x = 10*:

- *result<sub>0</sub> = 0<sup>2</sup> mod 10 = 0*
- *result<sub>1</sub> = 1<sup>2</sup> mod 10 = 1*
- *result<sub>2</sub> = 2<sup>2</sup> mod 10 = 4*
- *result<sub>3</sub> = 3<sup>2</sup> mod 10 = 9*
- *result<sub>4</sub> = 4<sup>2</sup> mod 10 = 6*